# FreeTextBox can't load dependency but it works

Tags: asp.net, freetextbox

I am having a bizarre problem. I installed FreeTextBox for my ASP.NET project (WebForms) and I set it all up and its working perfectly, it does what needs to be done. In the solution though, after a few compiles, I get the following error:

```
Error   1   'Could not load file or assembly 'FreeTextBox, Version=3.3.1.12354,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5962a4e684a48b87' or one of its dependencies. 
Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)'
```

The error is in the licenses.licx file. If I delete that line the program compiles without issue and I can use it, but after several compilations the problem pops back up and I need to delete it. I verified around the internet and found no defining answer to be honest.

Comment: Someone? Anyone? It keeps coming back on the Devops build server.
Yes; ofcourse we all tried all the usual suspects. Nugetpkg, restart, reinstall, reboot, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Did you download freetextbox.dll from the web? If yes, then right click and choose 'Unblock'. It might have been blocked for some reasons.